# How to resolve java.net.SocketException: Connection reset exception in java with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

When I am trying to `driver.close()` then I can get:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset exception.
```

How to resolve it?

I'm writting a code like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Log Out']")).click();
driver.close();
```

Comment: Please share the full error trace.

Comment: please check that you have strong internet connection

Answer (score 1):

You have version problems

1. Check your chromedriver version
2. Check your chrome version
3. Check your selenium version

They all should be compatible with each other

For example, if you are using chrome browser version `'Version 95.0.4638.69'` you should have the same version for chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the residual chores generated during the test execution and interfere in your next test execution, instead of `driver.close()` always invoke **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to close & **destroy** the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.